# Can't create bucket due to name already used

Tags: google-cloud-storage

A few weeks ago I deleted a bucket whose name I'd like to reuse, the google developers console is not letting me use that name telling me the name is already in use. Is there a default time that google keeps the bucket name around after it has been deleted? Can it be removed so I can reuse it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a bucket has been deleted, after a fairly short period, they usually becomes available to be claimed by others. Your bucket name may have been taken by someone else.

Comment: I deleted it 2-3 weeks ago, is that still a "short period"? It's highly unlikely the name was claimed by someone else, it contained a 20 character alpha-num random sequence, I think I have better odds at winning the lottery than it getting claimed by someone else

Comment: Hrm, it should be more on the order of seconds. If it's unlikely someone else claimed it, are you completely sure that it doesn't exist, perhaps under another of your projects? Tell ya what, please email the bucket name to gs-team@google.com and I will check on its status for you.

Comment: Email sent referencing this post. I can't say I'm sure it doesn't exist because the evidence points to the contrary, but I'm sure I deleted it and the project it belonged to. I've navigated the GDC site and I have no other projects or buckets. Just yesterday I created a new project with a similar bucket name minus the last character, but for the original I still get a 'name already in use' error.

Comment: Thanks, emailed you directly.

Comment: So for the benefit of the community, it turns out that if you delete a project without deleting the buckets contained within first, said buckets will go to a purgatory of sorts and will eventually be deleted, somewhere in the order of months however. So if you ever want to reuse a bucket name, make sure you delete directly first!